# Getting a Snapshotting Error when leaving app after Keyboard was shown (requires afterScreenUpdates:YES)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

I am currently starting a new test project for importing a client certificate via a separate (modal) view. The App always starts with a View "Main View" ([Main View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtFsC.png)), where I have some dummy elements to test if the connection works. Once a user adds a file to my app (e.g., opening it in mail or drag&drop in simulator), the "Certificate Import" View is shown via a Segue. When the user taps the "Enter Certificate Password" textfield, the keyboard pops up. On return .resignFirstResponder() is called and the app via label if the entered password is correct for the imported p12 client cert. I want my "Certificate Import" View ([Certificate Import View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSxeq.png)) to get dismissed when the app is closed or multitasking is activated. I realised this by calling dismiss(animated:completion:) in the Application delegate's applicationWillResignActive(application:) method on the CertificateImportViewController.

Now, my problem occurs when I close my app or switch to multitasking ONLY after the keyboard was shown in the "Certificate Import View".

When I close/multitask the app in the following states, I get the respective entry in debugger console:

1. When the keyboard is/was shown and I am in Certificate Import View:
   `[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fa91506b200, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.`
2. Even when I left Certificate Import View and am back in the "Main View": `[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fa91506b200, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.`
3. After I had the keyboard shown in Certificate Import View, left the app, open the app again and then close/multitask the app:`[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7f99e3821600, UIKeyboardImpl) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.`

I tried to find out what makes the OS think it has to take a snapshot including the keyboard even though the Main view never does show a keyboard. I also tried to find out why the keyboard believes it has to snapshot the keyboard after it has been dismissed (resignFirstResponder()). I am not sure how to debug what keeps my Certificate Import View on the stack (which I believe could be a reason).

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    guard let rv = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else {
        print("No Navigation Controller")
        return
    }

    if let r = rv.presentedViewController as? UINavigationController, let c = r.topViewController as? CertificateImportViewController {
        c.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    self.fileBlobURL = url

    guard let rv = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else {
        print("No Navigation Controller")
        return false
    }

    guard let myEntryViewController = rv.topViewController, myEntryViewController.title == "MainView" else {
        print("Wrong View Controller")
        return false
    }

    myEntryViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowCertificateImport", sender: myEntryViewController)

    return true
}
```

**CertificateImportViewController.swift**

```
class CertificateImportViewController: UIViewController {

    var fileURL: URL?
    var credential: URLCredential?

    @IBOutlet weak var certpwTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var certResult: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        certpwTextField.delegate = self

        let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        guard let u = appdelegate.fileBlobURL else {
            print("No file blob path found!")
            return
        }

        self.fileURL = u
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        certpwTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        certpwTextField.delegate = nil

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research including lots of trial and error I realised that:

- this is not the way I should handle "hiding sensitive information" when my app goes to background, [see Apple's Q&A 1838](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1838/_index.html)
- this might also be a bug as proposed in this [Apple developer forum post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63306)

However, if anyone in the future finds a solution to fix this, out of curiousity I would be highly interested in how it was done.

Comment: I get the same issue on iOS 13 when press home key to put my app to background, ```Snapshotting a view (0x1321a7000, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.``` which is not exist in previous iOS 12.

Comment: I don't even know why I start seeing this error in the logs out of nowhere.

Comment: Same for me, only in simulator, Xcode 15.0.1 iOS 17.0. This occurs when I return to app after going from the app to system settings (to change the app language).