# iOS 14 app killed immediately after being minimized and receiving snapshot warning

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift5, ios14

My IOS 14 app is always being killed immediately when it is being minimized. I have already added background modes: background fetch and background processing. However, when the app goes into the background and I switch to another app, XCode is telling me this:

Snapshotting a view (0x7f91ed844000, UIKeyboardImpl) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES

So I thought maybe the app can't create screenshots for the app switcher and Apple then just kills the app. My problem is that the message doesn't tell me how I can add this to the view. The documentation doesn't help me either also Google and searching here doesn't help. Everything I find is about how to take a screenshot and save it somewhere which is not what I am trying to do. Does anyone have an idea how I can approach this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That snapshot message is a warning and not relevant to your problem. Do you have the double negative "Application does not run in background" set to YES in your plist? Should be NO (or just omitted)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have checked my info.plist but it wasn't set there unfortunately. Adding it as NO doesn't have any effect (as expected, you already wrote that it can be omitted), but I tried it anyway.

Comment: Go to Settings/Developer and make sure that Fast App Termination is turned off.

Comment: I have checked it now, but it was already turned off.

Comment: @MikeQuade were you able to find a solution

Comment: @Nassif I put this item on hold for a while to be able to work on other parts of the app. Some time later I noticed that it was working. I'm not sure what the problem was unfortunately.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I'm having this snapshotting warning also when the keyboard is closed and I exit the app, do you know any solution for that or I can ignore it ?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898912/getting-a-snapshotting-error-when-leaving-app-after-keyboard-was-shown-requires